# Connect to external MySQL database from Docker container using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, docker, sqlalchemy

I am trying to **connect to an external MySQL database with public IP from a Docker container** with no success. The script I am trying to execute is Python with `sqlalchemy` and `pymysql`. **The script works correctly if I execute it directly**, but it fails when I try to execute it from the docker container.

I have tried using several networking options (`--add-host`, `--network`, ...), but they didn't work (or I used them wrong).

My Dockerfile is like this:

```sh
FROM python:3.8

# Copy project folder
COPY . /my_project
WORKDIR /my_project

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Define entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

My `main.py` file is like this:

```py
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote


def main():
    host = os.environ["DB_HOST"]
    user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
    password = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
    database = os.environ["DB_NAME"]

    engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{quote(password)}@{host}:3306/{database}")
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    print("Ok!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I build the Dockerfile with:

```sh
docker build -t my_project .
```

I run the docker image with:

```sh
docker run --env-file credentials.txt -p 3306:3306 my_project
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 613, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (my IP ofuscated for security)"\' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 13, in main
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3245, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3215, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2069, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (my IP ofuscated for security)"\' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```